# YIKES! I've run out of reviews in the close queue but I still have close votes!

Tags: discussion, cleanup

Well, the 10kers (users with more than 10,000 reputation) there's the [close queue](https://askubuntu.com/tools?tab=Close&daterange=last30days) in the form of 10k-tools, but mere mortals doesn't have this tool at all. But, don't exasperate, you still can spend them using the [following query](http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/182321). Take into account that the data is dumped weekly, so you may or may not find weird stuff like things with 5 close votes which ain't closed or with 4 close votes that doesn't have any.

Comment: and post things in the [regulators room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/206/ubuntu-regulators) that need closing and vote to close anything there (if it deserves closing that is).

Comment: Now we have 50 close votes to spend everyday! \o/ http://i.stack.imgur.com/AU1cv.jpg

Comment: This is excellent, well done!

Comment: @EricCarvalho but still only 20 review votes :P